# How to return if a transaction is committed or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to check if the transaction is committed or not and return the value.

I have written the below code but i am not sure how to return the if it is success or not.

```
public Task Insert(List<PortfolioCompanyLinkModel> record, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in record)
            {
                PortfolioCompanyLink portfolioCompanyLink = new PortfolioCompanyLink();
                portfolioCompanyLink.PortfolioCompanyId = item.PortfolioCompanyId;
                portfolioCompanyLink.URL = item.URL;
                portfolioCompanyLink.LinkId = item.LinkId;
                portfolioCompanyLink.CreatedBy = portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedBy = _loggedInUser;
                portfolioCompanyLink.CreatedOn = portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.AddAsync(portfolioCompanyLink, cancellationToken);
            }
            transaction.Commit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
    //return _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.AddAsync(record, cancellationToken);
}
```

Please help me to write the return statement here

Comment: Don't use a different return value, instead rethrow the exception that caused the rollback.

Comment: @Alejandro i want to return on success

Comment: BTW, you don't need transactions with EF Core, unless you used the generic repository *anti*pattern that breaks the ORM's data access flow. `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync`use transactions internally and are essentially atomic. Just add all the entities to the context and call `SaveChanges` once you leave the loop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you show me an example

Comment: The only reason you'd want a transaction would be for `AddAsync` to call `SaveChangesAsync` explicitly, even though there's no reason to. This results in N queries and N network roundtrips, instead of a single call. Worse, you have no idea how many changes `SaveChangesAsync` will save. It's *NOT* just the latest change, it will save all active changes. The first time you call `AddAsync` you may actually end up deleting a few rows and updating some others

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you help me by editing this code?

Comment: You're asking people to guess what your code does - for starters, there's no `AddAsync` method. The real `Add` is an in-memory operation, so there's no reason to run asynchronously. I suspect you created an extension method that calls `Insert() and then `SaveChangesAsync`. The solution is to just call `Insert` directly and then, *after* the loop exits, call `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos right but then i want the insert to happen after transaction is commited

Comment: Which is what EF Core will do when you call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync`. Again, what does `AddAsync` do? Does it call `SaveChanges` for every single object?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but then how will i rollback in catch?

Comment: I already explained that `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. You won't have to roll back or even start your own transaction. `SaveChanges` will start one and roll it back if saving fails.Check [the Basic Save- Multiple Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic#multiple-operations-in-a-single-savechanges) example in the docs, esp. the note `For most database providers, SaveChanges is transactional.`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a value that indicates whether "it is success or not", you should change the return type of your method to `Task<bool>` and return a `bool`:

```
public async Task<bool> Insert(List<PortfolioCompanyLinkModel> record, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in record)
            {
                PortfolioCompanyLink portfolioCompanyLink = new PortfolioCompanyLink();
                portfolioCompanyLink.PortfolioCompanyId = item.PortfolioCompanyId;
                portfolioCompanyLink.URL = item.URL;
                portfolioCompanyLink.LinkId = item.LinkId;
                portfolioCompanyLink.CreatedBy = portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedBy = _loggedInUser;
                portfolioCompanyLink.CreatedOn = portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                await _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.AddAsync(portfolioCompanyLink, cancellationToken);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above sample code I have also marked the method as `async` and awaited the `AddAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status
```

to get the status:

[TransactionStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionstatus?view=netframework-4.8)

It is an enum. As per MSDN:

Aborted 2
The transaction has been rolled back.

Active  0
The status of the transaction is unknown, because some participants must still be polled.

Committed   1
The transaction has been committed.

InDoubt 3

Your code can look like:

```
public Task Insert(List<PortfolioCompanyLinkModel> record, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in record)
            {
                PortfolioCompanyLink portfolioCompanyLink = new PortfolioCompanyLink();
                portfolioCompanyLink.PortfolioCompanyId = item.PortfolioCompanyId;
                portfolioCompanyLink.URL = item.URL;
                portfolioCompanyLink.LinkId = item.LinkId;
                portfolioCompanyLink.CreatedBy = portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedBy = _loggedInUser;
                portfolioCompanyLink.CreatedOn = portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.AddAsync(portfolioCompanyLink, cancellationToken);
            }
            transaction.Commit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }

       finally
       {
           var status = transaction.TransactionInformation.Status;
           if (status.Committed)
               return true;

           return false;  
       }
    }


    //return _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.AddAsync(record, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to write such code. The return is already known at the end of each block

Answer (score 0):

mm8's answer explains how to return true/false if the code succeeds or not. There's no reason to check the transaction's state, since it's the code itself that calls Commit or Rollback. Even if `Commit` throws, the `catch` block will execute - and throw again, since the transaction is already rolled back.

There's no need for such code in EF/EF Core though. A DbContext caches all changes and *only* saves them to the database when `SaveChanges` is called. The section [Multiple operations in a Single SaveChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic#multiple-operations-in-a-single-savechanges) in the [Basic Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic) tutorial explains :

> For most database providers, SaveChanges is transactional. This means all the operations will either succeed or fail and the operations will never be left partially applied.

All that's needed to save multiple objects to the database is :

```
foreach (var item in record)
{
    PortfolioCompanyLink portfolioCompanyLink = new PortfolioCompanyLink();
    .....
   //In-memory operation only. Doesn't need awaiting. Doesn't change the database
   //This only modifies the in-memory entities tracked by the context
   _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.Add(portfolioCompanyLink);
}
//Writes *all* changes to the database in a single transaction
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

There's no need for explicit transactions. `SaveChangesAsync` will roll back any changes and throw if anything goes wrong.

In fact, trying to call `SaveChangesAsync` on every step the way the custom `AddAsync` method seems to do, will have unexpected consequences. `SaveChangesAsync` saves *all* changes, not just the last one. If that context has pending deletions of updates, the first call to `AddAsync` may end up deleting or updating records.

The other problem with explicit long-running transactions is they seriously harm scalability even for small applications. A transaction keeps update on the rows and tables it touches, blocking *other* transactions. Keeping a transaction live without a reason results in blocking and even deadlocks.

Comment: how do i do if i need to update multiple items in the database? how will this line look like _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.Add(portfolioCompanyLink);for update?

Comment: You mentioned if i need to add a new value but what i want to update an existing value?

Comment: @HarshaMullangi that's explained in the docs. It's basic EF functionality. If you load an item with EF and modify it, the changes are tracked and `SaveChanges` will generate the appropriate `UPDATE` statements. You don't need to add extra code. If you have a [disconnected entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) eg a DTO with the new state of an object, the linked doc explains how that works - if you know the entity needs updating, you can use `DbContext.Update`.

Comment: Because you don't need one. If it succeeds, it just returns. If not, it throws. Besides, what does your `AddAsync` method do? It doesn't seem to be returning anything either

Comment: it return success or failure as 1 or 0

Comment: You still haven't added the code for that method, forcing everyone to just guess. In any case, what kind or return value do you want? You don't need any value to indicate success. [SaveChangesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_SaveChangesAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) returns the number of modified records. If SaveChanges fails you get an exception. You don't need anything else